Restructure PGP Keys
How do I restructure my keys from current/old setup to new setup?
The new setup would allow better key-management: isolation of primary-key and rotation of sub-keys.
Current/Old Setup:
PrimaryKey - CS
SubKey - E
New Setup:
PrimaryKey - C
SubKey1 - E
Subkey2 - S
I think of four options.
Option 1:
Create new SubKey with S-only and change usage of PrimaryKey to C-only.
Option 2:
Create new PrimaryKey with C-only and add the OldPrimaryKey+OldSubKey as SubKeys, by the method mentioned at https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32935/migrating-gpg-master-keys-as-subkeys-to-new-master-key
Option 3:
Create new PrimaryKey with C-only and add the OldPrimaryKey+OldSubKey as SubKeys, using 'addkey'+'Existing key' option.
Option 4:
Do a complete key transition. Create new set of keys: PrimaryKey-C, SubKey-S, and SubKey-E. Then, sign the new key using the old key to certify transition.
Thoughts?

I've ruled out Option 2 as it seems to be unreliable.
I was able to successfully test option 3.
The migrated keys retained the keygrip but not the fingerprint.
The migrated S-key and E-key weren't able to verify past signatures and decrypt past data, respectively. Thus, the migrated keys are functionally new keys.
Also, not sure whether keys with same keygrip but different fingerprints across key groups would cause any issues during cryptographic operations.
So, I've ruled this out too.
The option 1 is simple with no caveats.
The same PrimaryKey can continued to be used for C, the same SubKey1 can continued to be used for E, and the new SubKey2 can be used for S.
Also, it retains my identity as the PrimaryKey's fingerprint remains the same.
Option 4 is little nuanced, without caveats.
There'll be new PrimaryKey for C, and new SubKeys for S and E separately.
The old keys can be revoked and used for verifying signatures and decrypting old data.
Identity isn't preserved implicitly because of the new PrimaryKey and its fingerprint. However, the identity can be restored through Key Transition statement.
So, the option 1 is the way to go for restructuring keys with least hassles.
That said, I went with option 4. It's because I also wanted to change the key-type of PrimaryKey. In my old setup, both PrimaryKey and SubKey are ECC. I want the new setup to have RSA as PrimaryKey and ECC as SubKeys.
RSA is the only key-type that can have all the capabilities (C, S, E, and A). If a need arises where I've to use the PrimaryKey for other than C, I can just toggle the capabilities by editing the key. This isn't possible for DSA, Elgamal, or ECC. The only caveat of RSA in contrast to ECC is not security but efficiency (performance and storage). Since the PrimaryKey isn't gonna be used for day-to-day operations or stored on Key Cards, the caveat doesn't apply here.
My new setup has RSA PrimaryKey for C-only, Ed25519 SubKey1 for S, and X25519 SubKey2 for E.
My key transition statement can be found at https://www.raghavgururajan.name/rg-keytransition-statement.txt
